# Geoserver rendering hindi labels incorrectly

Tags: geoserver, sld

[image]

I have published a layer in geoserver with database. Unfortunately geoserver is not rendering the label correctly as its in database. I have included Hindi font both in sld and geoserver but I was unsuccessful. Please provide some way out to over come the above problem. Can you tell how a hindi font can be used in geoserver.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GIS.SE. Could you edit your question to explain what precisely is wrong, and what output is expected?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused question and answer format.  As @ArMoraer has mentioned, please [edit] your question to include more information about what is or isn't happening, a little bit about your setup, and what you've tried.

Comment: as i explained in this discussion (http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Hindi-Labels-issue-in-SLD-td5278689.html) none of the devs can read Hindi so we need more help